# Frame two non-nested for loops in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

So I have the alphabet, and I want to create a dictionary where each character in the alphabet is paired with its reverse, i.e. a is paired with z, b with y, etc.

I am trying to use list comprehension to create said dictionary.
My code as follows:

`{x:y for x in alphabet for y in alphabet[::-1]}`

Instead of iterating through x and y at the same time it nests x within y. What is the correct way to order this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
{x:y for (x, y) in zip(alphabet, alphabet[::-1])}
```

Here is a working example:

```
In [28]: import string

In [29]: alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

In [30]: {x:y for (x, y) in zip(alphabet, alphabet[::-1])}
Out[30]:
{'a': 'z',
 'b': 'y',
 'c': 'x',
 'd': 'w',
 'e': 'v',
 'f': 'u',
 'g': 't',
 'h': 's',
 'i': 'r',
 'j': 'q',
 'k': 'p',
 'l': 'o',
 'm': 'n',
 'n': 'm',
 'o': 'l',
 'p': 'k',
 'q': 'j',
 'r': 'i',
 's': 'h',
 't': 'g',
 'u': 'f',
 'v': 'e',
 'w': 'd',
 'x': 'c',
 'y': 'b',
 'z': 'a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[::-1])).
```

Output should be something like

```
>>> sorted(dict(zip(alpha, alpha[::-1])).items())
[('a', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'w'), ('e', 'v'), ('f', 'u'), ('g', 't'), ('h', 's'), ('i', 'r'), ('j', 'q'), ('k', 'p'), ('l', 'o'), ('m', 'n'), ('n', 'm'), ('o', 'l'), ('p', 'k'), ('q', 'j'), ('r', 'i'), ('s', 'h'), ('t', 'g'), ('u', 'f'), ('v', 'e'), ('w', 'd'), ('x', 'c'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'a')]
```

Comment: `dict(X).items()` is pretty much the same as `X` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

`dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[::-1]))`.
Output should be something like

```
>>> sorted(dict(zip(alpha, alpha[::-1])).items())
[('a', 'z'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x'), ('d', 'w'), ('e', 'v'), ('f', 'u'), ('g', 't'), ('h', 's'), ('i', 'r'), ('j', 'q'), ('k', 'p'), ('l', 'o'), ('m', 'n'), ('n', 'm'), ('o', 'l'), ('p', 'k'), ('q', 'j'), ('r', 'i'), ('s', 'h'), ('t', 'g'), ('u', 'f'), ('v', 'e'), ('w', 'd'), ('x', 'c'), ('y', 'b'), ('z', 'a')]
```

Comment: This just plagiarizes the other answer that came before. I regret to have edited this to look better.